# The form does not close

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a dummy installation of an antivirus, and **when the counter is equal to 0 I want the installation form to close** (eighth row **from the bottom**) and the other form to open. In execution once the counter has reached 0 only the other form opens and the first form does not close. I don't understand why this happens .... This is the code of the first form (the installation one):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class fakedownloadform : Form
        {
            public fakedownloadform()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void btn_annulla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            private System.Windows.Forms.Timer aTimer;
            private int counter = 60;
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                aTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                aTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_faketimer_Tick);
                aTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
                aTimer.Start();
                lbl_time.Text = counter.ToString();
                fakeprogresswnload.Increment(1);
                fakeprogresswnload.Maximum = 100;
                
                
            }
            private void tm_faketimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                fakedownloadform f1 = new fakedownloadform();
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                
                counter--;
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    aTimer.Stop();
                }
                lbl_time.Text = counter.ToString();
                if (counter == 55)
                {
    
                    fakeprogresswnload.Increment(8);
                    lbl_perc.Text = "8%";
    
                }
    
                else if (counter == 45) {
    
    
                    fakeprogresswnload.Increment(25);
                    lbl_perc.Text = "25%";
                }
    
                else if (counter == 37) {
    
    
                    fakeprogresswnload.Increment(32);
                    lbl_perc.Text = "61%";
                
                }
    
                else if (counter == 25)
                {
    
    
                    fakeprogresswnload.Increment(49);
                    lbl_perc.Text = "99%";
    
                }
    
    
    
                else if (counter == 0){
                    fakeprogresswnload.Increment(50);
                    lbl_perc.Text = "100%";
                    f1.Close();
                    f2.Show();
                }
    
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you cannot close the main form of an application (without closing the whole app). you need to rethink how your app is organized and maybe hide the main form while the other one is on the screen or something similar.

You can do something like this,

```
 Form2 f2 = new Form2();
 f2.Show();
 this.Hide();
```

But if you still want to close the form1 then you need to program your Program.cs file like,

```
 static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
```

Now you will be able to close the form1 and your application won't terminate. This allows the main thread to continue even if the current form is closed.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
 this.Close();
 f2.Show();
```

You do have to be careful though and end the main thread when you want to end the program. You can do this in the "FormClosed" event by calling "Application.Exit()".